# Using aggregate function to return minimum value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

Please, help me to create a query to determine minimum `date_time` from the table below:

```
 ID  |  Name  |  Date_Time | Location
---------------------------------------
 001 |  John  | 01/01/2015 |   901
 001 |  john  | 02/01/2015 |   903
 001 |  john  | 05/01/2015 |   905
 001 |  john  | 06/01/2015 |   904
 002 |  Jack  | 01/01/2015 |   903
 002 |  Jack  | 03/01/2015 |   904
 002 |  Jack  | 04/01/2015 |   905
 003 |  Sam   | 01/01/2015 |   904
 003 |  Sam   | 03/01/2015 |   903
 003 |  Sam   | 04/01/2015 |   901
 003 |  Sam   | 06/01/2015 |   903
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MIN(DATE_TIME), LOCATION
  FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY (ID)
```

but I got this error message:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: Where is your `FROM` clause?

Comment: Either include name in GROUP BY, or remove from select list. Same for location.

Answer (score 1):

If you use aggregation function, you have specify for which fields the agregation should be applied. So you are using group by clause. In this case you probably mean to find the minimum date_time for each id, name combination.

```
 select id, name, min(date_time) 
              from my_table group by id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

When you group something, all other rows will be left clustered to that grouped key. For a key, you can only fetch one of the row(entity) in `SELECT`.

Shortcut is, what ever in `GROUP BY` can be in `SELECT` freely. Otherwise, they have to be enclosed in a `AGGREGATE` function.

When you group by id,

`001` key has 4 rows clustered to it.. Just think, what would happen when you specify non grouped column in `SELECT`. Where-as when you use `MIN(date)`.. out of 4 dates, a minimum of one is taken.

So, your query has to be

```
SELECT ID,MIN(NAME),MIN(LOCATION),MIN(DATE)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

OR

```
SELECT ID,LOCATION,NAME,MIN(DATE)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID,LOCATION,NAME
```

OR

**Analytical approach.**

```
SELECT ID,LOCATION,DATE,MIN(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL) AS MIN_DATE
FROM TABLE.
```

Still, it is upto the requirements, on how the query has to be re-written.

**EDIT:** To fetch rows corresponding the Min date, we can create a SELF JOIN like one below.

```
SELECT T.ID,T.NAME,T.LOCATION,MIN_DATE
FROM
 (
   SELECT ID,MIN(DATE) AS MIN_DATE
   FROM TABLE T1
   GROUP BY ID
 ) AGG, TABLE T
 WHERE T.ID = AGG.ID
 AND T.DATE = AGG.MIN_DATE
```

OR

```
SELECT ID,NAME,LOCATION,MIN_DATE
FROM
( 
  SELECT ID,
         NAME,
         LOCATION,
         MIN(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL) MIN_DATE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL) RNK
  FROM TABLE
)
WHERE RNK = 1;
```

Comment: Yes you are right i need minimum datetime with its location field , name so for that reason i grouped only id .

Comment: @Nawaf Updated answer. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping all the other columns ... and if the table is name 'table' try changing the table name to something else in the schema.

```
SELECT ID , NAME , MIN(DATE_TIME) , LOCATION FROM TABLE  GROUP BY ID, Name, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

select t1.name,t1.id,t1.location,t1.date from (select id,MIN(Date) as min_date from table group by id ) t2 inner join TABLE t1 on t1.date=t2.min_date and t1.id=t2.id;